# Change table column

Tags: sql

I have this query that I'm trying to use it works great and it gives me the right format but the results is a list of dates.  What I'm trying to do is change the SALEDATE column in the SALEH
IST4 table from  "2004-06-08 00:00:00.0000000" to 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

```
 USE taxpayer
 SELECT FORMAT(SALEDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US')  AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
 FROM VISION_SALEHIST4;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product - and date/time formatting functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also post the schema of the table, example input data, current output, and desired output.

Comment: Your question sounds like you are trying to alter the contents of a table. SELECT just *reports* on content. Plus you want to store dates as some date type, not as formatted string

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *type* of the column:

```
alter table VISION_SALEHIST4 alter column saledate date;
```

This changes it to a date.  You can format it as you like when you use it.  Do not store dates as strings.

Or, perhaps you should just add a computed column:

```
alter table VISION_SALEHIST4 add saledate_mmddyyyy as
     (FORMAT(SALEDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US'));
```

Then you can show `saledate_mmddyyyy` and still use `saledate` for filtering, aggregation, ordering, and other purposes.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc912fa8ea2798410249842f07af8eca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I'm getting an error message "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'."  When I used the above query.alter table VISION_SALEHIST4 add column saledate_mmddyyyy as
     (FORMAT(SALEDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US'));

Comment: @Chris . . . The `column` is not allowed here.  That always gets me because it is required for `alter column`.